# ImmutableJS Set not flattening

Tags: javascript, list, immutable.js, ecmascript-6

I have the following code:

```
Immutable.Set(['valor1', 'valor2', 'valor2', 'valor3', ['valor4', 'valor5']]).flatten().toJS();
```

This doesn't work as expected, but returns the like it was inputted. If I treat it as a List, it works as expected:

```
   Immutable.fromJS(['valor1', 'valor2', 'valor2', 'valor3', ['valor4', 'valor5']]).flatten().toJS(); // return flattened list
```

What's wrong with *flatten* function when using it with Set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What's wrong with flatten function when using it with Set?

Nothing is wrong with it. It seems you have to wrong idea about how `Set` and `flatten` work. From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Set/flatten):

> Flattens only others Iterable, not Arrays or Objects.

`Immutable.fromJS(...)` *deeply* converts the value to Maps and Lists, so the inner array is converted to an `Immutable.List`, and that's why it works. The constructor functions do *not* deeply convert, and so the set contains an array (which is not flattened).

Comment: Immutable List is an Iterable and Immutable Set not?

Comment: No. A set is also an iterable.

Comment: So it doesn't make sense to work with List and not with Set

Comment: Again: If you use `fromJS(...)`, the inner array is converted to a List -> Iterable. If you use `Set(...)`, the inner array stays an array and `flatten` doesn't flatten arrays. Try `Immutable.List(['valor1', 'valor2', 'valor2', 'valor3', ['valor4', 'valor5']]).flatten().toJS();` and you get the same result.

Comment: Immutable.Set doesn't make a Set (Iterable) with the given array?

Comment: Not the inner array. None of the constructors do. Only `fromJS` deeply converts the value: *"Deeply converts plain JS objects and arrays to Immutable Maps and Lists."* https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS

Comment: But Immutable.fromJS returns a List, and not a Set.

Comment: I know. What's your point? You asked why it works with `fromJS` and not with `Set`. I believe I answered that question.

Comment: That's what you are already doing. It seems what you actually want to know is how to deeply convert arrays to Sets. There is probably not an easy way, so how about you do `Immutable.fromJS().flatten().toSet().toJS();` instead?

Comment: Sorry if I don't know the internals, I though I was clear. So I have to make a explicit conversion from List to Set? Is it performátic?